# Executables in subfolder in path

Tags: python, bash, path, directory-structure, project-structure

I wish to place my executables in subfolders:

```
    $ tree
    .
    ├── bin
    │   ├── exec.py
    │   ├── method1
    │   │   ├── exec1.py
    │   │   └── exec2.py
    │   └── method2
    │       ├── exec1.py
    │       └── exec2.py
```

If I include bin/ folder in PATH, is there a way to access executables from my shell script (which is in another directory), as e.g.

```
$ method1/exec1.py arg1 arg2
```

The above command gives an error (No such file or directory), but

```
$ exec.py arg1 arg2
```

works, as it is not in a subfolder.

Kindly advise how I can organise executable files in subfolders. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented [here](//www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Search-and-Execution.html), the bash shell (and probably most other shells too) only looks for the command on the $PATH if the command name contains no slashes.

There are several ways you can solve the issue:

1. You can make a folder containing [symbolic links](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux) to the commands and add that folder to the $PATH.
2. You can add the subfolders to the $PATH. If there are many subfolders you can [do it automatically](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/17715/142240)
3. You can change the scripts current directory to your bin. An easy way to temporarily change the current directory is to [use subshells](//stackoverflow.com/q/786376/5420829).
4. And of course you can try using a different shell that does the command search differently. Sorry, but I don't know where to find one, you'll have to google this yourself if you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Андрей Беньковский for the exhaustive answer. It is useful to know that command name should contain no slashes. As I have same exec filenames for different methods, I cannot put them together. My solution is to use a variable BINROOT=bin/ and call a command using

```
    $BINROOT/method1/exec1.py arg1 arg2
```